# How to draw sparkline for values which are not followed directly by each others

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sparklines

I have some values in cells that are not followed by each other and scattered in cells where some values for the cells are blank or I want to exclude from being shown up in the sparkline.

Example: I wanna show up sparkline for values A1:E1 but B1 contains value I don't want it to show in the sparkline.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Hi player0. here is it. thank you so much

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/109ye6t9ucTWxNc29dtAif0DTj3dNWme-MpcJnOCbAiA/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=SPARKLINE({D5, F5, H5:J5})
```

[image: 0]